# In Scala, how to do type conversion for Future[Option[A]]?

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, future

For example, there are two classes: `A` and `B`. And there is a method in `A` called `toB`.

Now there is a value `a` which is of type `Future[Option[A]]`, what will be the most elegant way to convert it to `Future[Option[B]]`?

Currently I'm using `a.map(_.map(_.toB))`, but I think it looks a bit clumsy and confusing. Does anyone have better ways to do this? (implicit conversion)
 Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosVilchez it doesn't work..

Comment: Are `A` & `B` completely unrelated classes?

Comment: map/map looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to operate a lot on the "stack" of `Future[Option[?]]` you can use a [monad transformer](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html):

```
val a: OptionT[Future, A] = OptionT(...)
val b: OptionT[Future, B] = a.map(_.toB)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to throw some `scalaz` in there, you could write a generic function for this:

```
 import scalaz._
 import Scalaz._

def mapF[F[_]: Functor, G[_]:Functor,A,B](fg: F[G[A]], h : A => B) : F[G[B]] =  fg.map( _.map(h))
```

It uses the "ugly" mapmap version, but it would work for any `Functor`.
If you want to use it infix, just create an implicit class for it:

```
  implicit class toMapF[F[_]:Functor,G[_]:Functor, A](fg : F[G[A]]){
    def mapF[B](f: A => B) = fg.map( _.map(f))
  }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
 a.mapF(_.toB)
```

This is of course absolute overkill unless you're already using `scalaz`, but any reason is good to try it out.

Comment: I think this already exists in scalaz as [`compose`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L62)?

Comment: It's honestly hard to find some abstraction that is not in `scalaz` already. I'm trying it with `Functor[List]`.compose.map(a)(_.toB)` but getting some 'implicit expansion` problem. It looks promising though, I'll try to make it work, thanks for pointing it out.